# Randomly shuffling a linked list

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a project and the last piece of functionality I have to write is to shuffle a linked list using the rand function.

I'm very confused on how it works.

Could someone clarify on how exactly I could implement this?

I've looked at my past code examples and what I did to shuffle an array but the arrays and linked lists are pretty different.

Edit:
For further clarifications my Professor is making us shuffle using a linked list because he is 'awesome' like that.

Comment: Are you oblige to do linked list? Why not vector? or list? In c++ linked list is useless

Comment: If you have some code that shuffles an array, just convert the list back and forth

Comment: My prof isn't allowing us to use arrays to shuffle. We are limited to link list.

Comment: I can help you, but are you sure you want c++ approach? It's very weird. In C in can try to explain how it's work, and in this case, it's very usefull.

Answer (score 2):

You can always add another level of indirection... ;)
(see [Fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering) in Wikipedia)

Just create an array of pointers, sized to the list's length, unlink items from the list and put their pointers to the array, then shuffle the array and re-construct the list.

**EDIT**

If you must use lists you might use an approach similar to merge-sort:

- split the list into halves,
- shuffle both sublists recursively,
- merge them, picking randomly next item from one or the other sublist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it gives a reasonable random distribution :D

```
bool randcomp(int, int)
{
    return (rand()%2) != 0;
}


mylist.sort(randcomp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterate over list several times and swap adjacent nodes with certain probablity. Something like this:

```
const float swapchance = 0.25;
const int itercount = 100;

struct node
{
    int val;
    node *next;
};

node *fisrt;

{ // Creating example list
    node *ptr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        node *tmp = new node;
        tmp.val = i;
        tmp.next = ptr;
        ptr = tmp;
    }
}

// Shuffling
for (int i = 0; i < itercount; i++)
{
    node *ptr = first;
    node *prev = 0;
    while (ptr && ptr->next)
    {
        if (std::rand() % 1000 / 1000.0 < swapchance)
        {
            prev->next = ptr->next;
            node *t = ptr->next->next;
            ptr->next->next = ptr;
            ptr->next = t;
        }
        prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The big difference between an array and a linked list is that when you use an array you can directly access a given element using pointer arithmetic which is how the `operator[]` works.

That however does not preclude you writing your own `operator[]` or similar where you walk the list and count out the nth element of the list. Once you got this far, removing the element and placing it into a new list is quite simple.

The big difference is where the complexity is O(n) for an array it becomes O(n^2) for a linked list.