# shuffling a linked list stack

Tags: c++, linked-list, shuffle

currently working on my project , and shuffling is the last function i have to write but i am confused and i dont know how

can anyone here help me ? thanks anyway !

so here is my class

```
//   Creating a NODE Structure
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;

};


// Creating a class STACK
class tumpukan
{
    struct node *top;
    public:
    tumpukan() // constructure
    {
        top=NULL;
    }
void push(int x)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=new node;
    ptr->data=x;
    ptr->next=NULL;
    if(top!=NULL)
    ptr->next=top;
    top=ptr;
}



int pop()
{
struct node *temp;
    if(top==NULL)
        {
            printf("Tumpukan Kosong \n");
        }
temp=top;
top=top->next;
return temp->data;
delete temp;
}



void show()
{
    struct node *ptr1=top;
    printf("isi tumpukan  : \n");
    while(ptr1!=NULL)
    {
    cout<<ptr1->data<<" ->";
    ptr1=ptr1->next;
    }
    printf("NULL \n");
}

};
```

any help is appreciated !

Comment: Why would you want to shuffle a stack? The point of a stack is to maintain FILO ordering, shuffling defeats that purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomly shuffling a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094055/randomly-shuffling-a-linked-list)

Comment: Please be more specific on the actual requirements. Also, why are you re-implementing from scratch instead of using concepts that are readily part of the language? Finally, your implementation still needs work (e.g. your pop method will still crash after printing "Empty Stack")

Comment: What's wrong with `std::shuffle` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a vector containing the addresses of all the nodes, call it V, and make a set of indices from 1 to N (N is the number of nodes), call it I. Create an empty stack S.
Now:(psuedocode)

```
for i in range 1 to V.size():
   index=I.pick_at_rand() // you can easily find these sort of functions
   I.delete(index)
   if(S.top!=NULL):
      V[i].next=S.top
      S.push(V[index])
   else:
      S.push(V[index])
```